# What is a word for a mixed-species group of animals?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

We have words like flock, gaggle, herd, and bevy for groups of animals of the same species. Is there a word for a group of animals of mixed species?

Something like, "I have a [word] of geese, goats, and chickens."

Comment: I have a barnyard full of ...  barnyard’s worth of ...  a whole bunch of ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Menagerie**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/menagerie) is a collection of animals and carries the sense of a varied mixture.

> He has a menagerie of animals in his home. 5 cats, 3 dogs, a bird, and 4 hamsters. The smell is unbearable.

Otherwise, you're describing a farm or a zoo ...